# Using generated captcha token to by pass recaptcha

Tags: node.js, recaptcha, captcha

I was using this captcha harvester (https://www.npmjs.com/package/captcha-harvester) on supremenewyork.com to figure out how to bypass a recaptcha with a generated token from this captcha-harvester but I have no idea where I would input the token after getting it to bypass recaptcha with it.

Answer (score 0):

i know its bet late but maybe others may benefit from my answer what u have to do is

```
await page.evaluateOnNewDocument(() => {
            const handleDocumentLoaded = () => {
              document.getElementById("g-recaptcha-response").innerHTML = {
                token,
              };
            };
            if (document.readyState === "loading") {
              document.addEventListener(
                "DOMContentLoaded",
                handleDocumentLoaded
              );
            } else {
              handleDocumentLoaded();
            }
          });
```

that worked with me.